# Native heap Android setup

Tags: android, heap-memory

I know I can get native heap by replacing system/lib/libc.so with /system/lib/libc_debug.so (actually I found ), and adding "native=true" to my ddms.cfg.
However, I couldn't replace the libc.so, no matter how I tried. I did this on emulator, because we don't have any rooted device. I tried via adb shell, from command line, but it says   I don't have permission to write. Tried chmod, no joy. 
How should I replace the file on the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't remount the system partition (/system).  It's mounted read only (even on the emulator), so chmod won't help.

Just do `adb remount`.  Check the output of `mount` run from a shell on the device to see the read/write status of any mount point.